# List of consecutive numbers repeated according to values in another list

Tags: python, list

My target is to get a list of consecutive numbers, repeated accordingly with the initial list values. Lets say I have:

```
initialList=[1,2,3,5]
```

And I want to get:

```
targetList=[0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
```

...I'm totally new with Python, sorry for this -probably- very first steps question. Tried many searchs but the results didn't match with my needs, unfortunately. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you got any attempts yet that you can show us? Where are you tripping up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The newbie-friendly solution is to use two loops:

```
result = []
number = 0
for repeat in initialList:
    for _ in range(repeat):
        result.append(number)
    number += 1

print(result)  # [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

If you prefer one-liners for whatever reason, you can combine [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to get

```
result = [num for num, repeat in enumerate(initialList) for _ in range(repeat)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
initialList=[1,2,3,5]
final_result = [i for b in [[c]*d for c, d in enumerate(initialList)] for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO, this is a more maintainable functional solution:

```
initialList = [1, 2, 3, 5]

def listify(x):
    return [x]

# create sub-lists [[0], [1], [2], [3], ...]
sublists = map(listify, range(len(initialList)))

# attach to each sub-list the repititions required [([0], 1), ([2], 2), ...]
sublists_with_rep_spec = zip(sublists, initialList)

# create repetitions based on initialList (using list multiplication)
sublists_with_repetitions = starmap(operator.mul, sublists_with_rep_spec)

# flatten everything out
result = chain.from_iterable(sublists_with_repetitions)

print(list(result))
```

Note that this is all lazy (on python3) so everything will "happen" only when you actually call `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using `repeat` and `chain.from_iterable`

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

list(chain.from_iterable((repeat(idx, num)) for idx, num in enumerate(initialList)))

[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution using `sum` and `enumerate`

```
initialList = [1, 2, 3, 5]

targetList  = sum((times*[index] for index, times in enumerate(initialList)), [])
```

Comment: Much better performant solution - using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` instead of `sum`: 
`itertools.chain.from_iterable(times*[index] for index, times in enumerate(initialList))` (need to `import itertools` and you get back an `iterator` instead of a `list` but that's negligible)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible via `itertools`, if you wish to remove the need for nested logic. `itertools` is part of the standard library.

For improving your understanding of Python, I recommend you see [@Ajax1234's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613385/9209546) for some nested list comprehensions.

```
from itertools import chain

initialList = [1,2,3,5]

targetList = list(chain.from_iterable([i]*j for i, j in enumerate(initialList)))

# [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

**Note**: you can replace `[i]*j` with `itertools.repeat(i, j)` or `numpy.repeat(i, j)` if you use `numpy`. The former may be preferable as it is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
data=[[i]*initialList[i] for i,j in enumerate(initialList)]

print([k for i in data for k in i])
```

Just for fun I tried with lambda :

```
initialList=[1,2,3,5]

print(list(map(lambda x:[x]*initialList[x],range(0,len(initialList)))))
```

lambda result is in nested list.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
>>> initialList=[1,2,3,5]
>>> sum(([num]*count for num, count in enumerate(initialList)), [])
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Using `sum` to flatten lists is horrible performance-wise. Really really bad. Use `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools`

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way:

```
from functools import reduce

initialList = [1,2,3,5]
targetList = [[index]*item for index, item in enumerate(initialList)]
targetList = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, targetList)
print(targetList)
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: the reduce is horrible performance-wise, it is also the same as `sum(targetlist, [])` (again, horrible) - use `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: @ReutSharabani There are many answers using `chain`, I thought I should not duplicate mine.

Comment: The current code creates linearily many intermediate lists. It is extremely wasteful.

Answer (score -1):

I find most of the current answers either poor performance-wise or hard to read. An alternative functional way of doing this would be by using such [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) functions as [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), and [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import chain, count, repeat

initial_list = [1, 2, 3, 5]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, count(), initial_list)))
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```